# Laravel Except Token Mismatch Error

Tags: laravel, token

My URL

```
http://laravel/tr/order/fp1/success
```

VerifyCsrfToken Except .

```
protected $except = [
    'order/*'
];
```

But i have Token Mismatch Error.

Update:

I'm posting data to external webpage (Bank Server) And They are posting to my site.

Comment: You placing `_token` if you generate the form manually ?

Comment: Then you should probably disable the csrf filter for that particular request

Comment: Wanted to know how ?

Comment: of course csrf filter. I've already exclude url from csrf filter. But i made something wrong. It is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.

In Except Property we have to write URI. But i didn't write language path.

```
protected $except = [
    'tr/order/*'
];
```

If i write language path. It is working. But hardcoding language path is not logical.

And i override shouldPassThrough of BaseVerifier in Laravel.

```
protected $except = [
    'order/*',
];

protected function shouldPassThrough($request)
{
    foreach ($this->except as $except) {
        if ($request->is(trim(Lang::locale().'/'.$except, '/'))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

We add `Lang::locale().'/'`

Now we can use except property without writing language path.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Op's comment it seems that the request is coming from external site where we can't generate csrf tokens from our application.

So, there is two possible solutions

**Method 1 :**

The request should get the csrf token from the application in prior request and then send the request with token

**Method 2 :**

You should attach a parameter with incoming request and have this inside the `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
$paramExist=  $request->yourSecretParam;
    #return parent::handle($request, $next);
        if(isset($paramExist))
        {
            $yourSpecialkey ='a2$%$'; #This to check whether the param has the value that you set
            if($paramExist==$yourSpecialKey)
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
            else
            {
                return parent::handle($request, $next);
            }

        }   
        else
        {
            return parent::handle($request, $next);
        }
```

By having this you can check whether the request matches not with the parameter value that the external application has.

Hope, this helps you

Comment: why won't we use protected property $except ?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but i crossed the same situation like yours and deal those in Middleware !